# Are observable created during buffer(bufferClosingSelector) automatically terminated

Tags: rx-java

My question is about the rxjava buffer(bufferClosingSelector) which at the beginning of each buffer calls a function which returns an observable which determines when the buffer closes.  My question is will that observable be terminated automatically when the buffer closes or do I need to ensure that myself?

Answer (score 0):

The `bufferClosingSelector` will emit as long the upstream observable is emitting, i.e, items are coming into the `buffer`. Once that upstream observable completes, the `bufferClosingSelector` completes as well and stops emitting.  You don't have to do anything to clean it up.

Comment: But if the upstream observable never terminates or goes a long time I guess one should take care to ensure that one is not creating an unbounded number of active observables.  Unless I'm missing something this answers my question.  Thanks.

Comment: @DavePosner, the `bufferClosingSelector` function is called only once, so only one observable will be created. That observable will emit until it is unsubscribed, which happens when the upstream observable terminates.

Answer (score 0):

This was a silly question based on my misreading of the docs.  In the version of the buffer operator I'm referring to here, the buffer is closed when the bufferClosingSelector *completes* (not when it emits an event).  Sorry.